# Is it possible to auto-deduce base class template parameters from constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

This code sample works and doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    base(T a) {};
};

struct b : public base<int> {
    b() : base(3) {};
};
```

I want to utilize C++17 feature with auto-deduction template parameters from constructor and do something like this:

```
struct b : public base { // note lack of <int>
    b() : base(3) {};
};
```

Is it possible at all without some ugly hacks?

Comment: Do you want `b` be template ?

Comment: You can write `struct b : public decltype(base(3))` in C++17, but that's not shorter than `struct b : public base<int>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The template argument deduction rules don't allow for it. And it's unlikely they ever will. Consider this:

```
struct b : public base { // note lack of <int>
    b()    : base(3) {}
    b(int) : base(false) {}
};
```

What is the base class of `b` now? One may argue that it's feasible if all initializations of the base class agree on the type. But it's hard to check that in practice (think separate object files where c'tors reside), and it seems IMO too niche of a feature to be useful.

So, to summarize, you can't avoid specifying the template arguments for the base class template.

Comment: Following on from your example; if you do something like `auto bar = foo ? "a" : 5` you get a compiler error; I don't see the issue with the compiler doing the same in this case

Comment: @UKMonkey - The type inference rules for the conditional operator don't need to account for the same open endendess that this feature has to deal with. It's not quite the same.

Comment: @UKMonkey - Also, this is also quite brittle. And innocent change in a member initialization list can break a build. And it won't be very clear WTH just happened. The conditional operator breaking is still a local error for the most part.

Comment: What is more likely happen is to allow this for function return types I think.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest they were the same - I was making the point that the compiler could just error in your example without trying to guess what type it should be - don't disagree with the brittle though!